# How to use continue for a while loop in a nested for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, continue

I'm trying to continue a while loop after a condition of an if statement is met, however, that if statement is in a for loop, and the continue statement is just continuing the for loop instead of the while loop. My code looks like this:

```
while (valid_input == false) {

    printf("Enter a date (yyyy/mm/dd): ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(date, 20, stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        if (!isdigit(date[i])) {
            printf("Error: You didn't enter a date in the format (yyyy/mm/dd)\n");
            continue;
        }

    }
```

How could I code this so I continue at the beginning of the while loop after the condition (!isdigit(date[i])) is met?

Comment: By not writing code like this.  Move the inner loop into a function that the outer loop calls, then you just need an `if` in the outer loop.  Or, just ditch the inner loop altogether and use `sscanf()` instead.

Comment: Instead of `continue` which will go to the next iteration of the `for` loop, simply do `i = 4`.      BTW:  since array indexing is zero based, it is more conventional in C++ for the end condition to be expressed using `<`, not `<=`  (e.g. `for (i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)`  rather than `for (i = 0; i <= array_size; ++i)` which will run past the end of the array).

Comment: Are you sure this is tagged correctly? This looks like a C problem, not a C++ problem.

Comment: @Tzalumen It's fine being tagged c++, both languages would behave the same regarding that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I ask because if the tags give the right coverage, people watching those tags are more likely to see the question, and the asker gets a greater possibility of help.

Comment: @Tzalumen c++ and c tags overlap to some extend.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use another boolean variable to indicate that you want to `continue` the outer loop and `break` executing the inner one:

```
while (valid_input == false) {

    printf("Enter a date (yyyy/mm/dd): ");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgets(date, 20, stdin);

    bool continue_while = false; // <<<
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

        if (!isdigit(date[i])) {
            printf("Error: You didn't enter a date in the format (yyyy/mm/dd)\n");
            continue_while = true; // <<<
            break; // <<< Stop the for loop
        }
    }
    if(continue_while) {
        continue; // continue the while loop and skip the following code
    }

    // Some more code in the while loop that should be skipped ...
}
```

Maybe just `break;` in the `for()` loop is already enough if there's no more code which needs to be skipped after.

Comment: Seriously, `goto` is clearer than those setting flags and jumping on ifs.

Comment: @luk32 That's your opinion, I have some principles to avoid `goto` as much as possible. Usually the code flow is more obfuscated using `goto`, than using clear conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible using `continue`, you would need to use `goto` or conditionals. Tough, in your particular case `break` would achieve the same result.

Btw. I am not jugdeing the design decision to handle date validation here. Just answering how to proceed to next `while` iteration.

Comment: _"It's impossible, you need to use `goto` or conditionals."_ Nonsense!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ How is it possible to use `continue` to escape to beyond enclosing loop?

Comment: @Tzalumen Why not, there is no other way to jump to the beginning of outer loop. It's by definition the same.

Comment: Because `goto` is considered harmful.

Comment: @Tzalumen Dealing with absolutes is more harmful. As I've said, that's the only way to jump to the beginning of the `while` like `continue` would. It would be deprecated if it was so bad. Look at at alternative in pantharei's answer. Another variable, break, and an ifjust to continue. I'm not sure if it's clearer or cleaner. IMHO not.

Comment: @luk32 Well, for the concrete example from the OP, simply `break;` would be fine. No need for either mechanisms.

Comment: Just because it answers the letter of the question, does not mean we should offer it as the answer. We should guide him to produce good code that does what he actually wants it to do.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Of course. That's what my answer said from it's inception, (*before yours did actually*). The question is how to use `continue` to make the jump, the closest general form is `goto`, here a `break` is fine. I don't use `goto`, but here it really makes sense over a conditional. IMHO. It's literally `goto next_while_iteration` vs a break, flag, and conditional if... what's easier to read and maintain? I accept the public vote =] But pending delete vote is hurting a bit =/ Anyways, cheers.

Comment: @Tzalumen You see, my opinion on that is, that some day, someone might google, how do I really skip to the outer loop iteration, for example in a tight `for(;;){for(;;){}}` loop, and will see the title, and will be mad that no one answered the actual question. Also it litreally say's that it's only answers the original question and I am skipping a design class here. If you don't think it has it's merit, fine we can disagree. Conditionals are also bad. Remy's comments under question are the best advice in that regard. Anyway, cheers to you too. Good discussion.